# Load a page altogether with its dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am building a multi-page mobile web app where each page can optionally have its specific dialog(s). Is there a way to load the dialogs altogether with the pages?

`a.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>B4DATING</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Page A</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content"> 
    <a href="b.html" data-role="button">Push me</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`b.html`

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Page B</h1>
    <a href="#menu" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn-right" data-rel="dialog">more</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content"> 
    Welcome to Page B!
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="dialog" id="menu" class="dialog-actionsheet">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
    <h1>Menu B</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d"  data-icon="false" class="jqm-list">
      <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Y</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need is to make the dialog work properly (without further AJAX requests). Just the entire HTML to be processed and imported into the DOM by jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Can you use popup widget instead of dialog (popups are contained within the page)?

Comment: Dialog in _b.html_ will be neglected when you load _b.html_ from _a.html_ via _Ajax_. Alternatively, you can change anchor `<a href="dialogB.html" data-rel="dialog">Dialog</a>`. Or you can load it `$.mobile.changePage("dialogB.html", { changeHash: false });`.

Comment: I will go for a popup, that's the only reasonable solution. Thanks @ezanker.